# QT Building Statically absolute nightmare! Any help on these errors?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, qt-creator, mingw32

I've been trying to build my QT application statically for a good few hours now and I just keep getting errors.

My QT configuration is:

- **QT Version**: 5.15.2
- **Compiler**: MinGW32
- **Build Tool**: CMake

The guide that has got me the furthest: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW

The process I have followed:

- Created a .bat file which contained the following `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static.ps1' -QtSrcUrl 'http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.15/5.15.2/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2.zip' -QtStaticDir 'C:\Qt\Static' -MingwDir 'C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32' -QtVersion '5.15.2-Static'`
- Run that bat file

Then I get the following errors after it compiles the files:

- mingw32-make: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
- mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:103: module-qtbase-install_subtargets]
  Error 2
- mingw32-make: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.

I decided to go into QT creator and set it as my active kit anyways, and it compiled just as if it was using the the MinGW compiler, which I assume is wrong because the [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/lwX_urJJOf8?t=1583) I was following shows 2 files "Debug" and "Release" whereas mine doesn't have these files and is displayed as follows:
[Directory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Asp8.png).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Below are the errors I receive:

```
mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:638:30: error: 'mimetype_database' was not declared in this scope
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database), "Bundled MIME database is empty");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:638:30: note: suggested alternative: 'mimeTypeForName'
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database), "Bundled MIME database is empty");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:639:52: error: 'MimeTypeDatabaseOriginalSize' was not declared in this scope
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database) <= MimeTypeDatabaseOriginalSize,
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:639:52: note: suggested alternative: 'QMimeDatabasePrivate'
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database) <= MimeTypeDatabaseOriginalSize,
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
 mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:638:30: error: 'mimetype_database' was not declared in this scope
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database), "Bundled MIME database is empty");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:638:30: note: suggested alternative: 'mimeTypeForName'
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database), "Bundled MIME database is empty");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:639:52: error: 'MimeTypeDatabaseOriginalSize' was not declared in this scope
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database) <= MimeTypeDatabaseOriginalSize,
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
mimetypes\qmimeprovider.cpp:639:52: note: suggested alternative: 'QMimeDatabasePrivate'
     Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(sizeof(mimetype_database) <= MimeTypeDatabaseOriginalSize,
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
global/qglobal.h:121:68: note: in definition of macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
 #  define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
```

Comment: The message "Target 'install' not remade because of errors." means that actual error message is somewhere **above**. Without that message we cannot help you to fix it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev my bad I didn't realise they were being displayed, everything just fly's by, I've updated my question with 2 images outlining the errors.

Comment: No, do not show **image** with the error. Instead, paste the error message into the question post, as **text**. You may format pasted message as a code, using `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, I think that's it now.

Comment: It looks like the known problem for QT15: https://forum.qt.io/topic/118511/static-qt-environment-error-using-qt5-15-0. And it is not solved yet.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ahhh thats an annoyance. I really appreciate you researching that thank you very much